# Use output from "form" in HTML in an API link

Tags: javascript, html, forms, youtube

I have been working on a very simple YouTube Downloader on my [GitHub website](https://steepatticstairs.github.io/youtubedownloader/) based off of the [loader.to api](https://loader.to/api/). This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>
        <form>
            <label for="theurl">Youtube URL:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="theurl" name="theurl"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Ok">
        </form>
    </p>

        <iframe 
            style="width:800px;height:250px;border:0;overflow:hidden;" 
            scrolling="no" src="https://loader.to/api/card/?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">
        </iframe>
        
        <p><a href="https://replit.com/@Pufferfishe/YoutubeDownloader">replit code</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://youtubedownloader.pufferfishe.repl.co">replit website</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This essentially a webpage that displays a form box with a submit button, and then a pre-defined loader.to block, that only links to one download (in this case, Never Gonna Give You Up). How could I make it so that the YouTube url that you enter into the form box would generate the relevant loader.to card?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and with [events](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/Events).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript you can:

- Listen for the "submit" event on the form
- Stop the form from refreshing the page
- Get the YouTube URL from the input
- Set the "src" attribute on the iframe using the YouTube URL

See below for working example.

```js
// Listen for the "submit" event on the form
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', event => {

  // Stop the form from refreshing the page
  event.preventDefault() 
  
  // Get the YouTube URL from the input
  const youtubeUrl = document.querySelector('[name="theurl"]').value
  
  // Set the "src" attribute on the iframe using the YouTube URL
  document.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute('src', 'https://loader.to/api/card/?url=' + youtubeUrl)
})
```

```html
        <form>
            <label for="theurl">Youtube URL:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="theurl" name="theurl"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Ok">
        </form>

        <iframe 
            style="width:800px;height:250px;border:0;overflow:hidden;" 
            scrolling="no" src="https://loader.to/api/card/?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">
        </iframe>
        
        <p><a href="https://replit.com/@Pufferfishe/YoutubeDownloader">replit code</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://youtubedownloader.pufferfishe.repl.co">replit website</a></p>
```